# gphoto2 --capture-tethered capture event not being detected

Tags: libgphoto2

i'm running gphoto2 on a Linux Raspberry Pi, waiting for a photo to be taken on a Canon EOS 1200D which is connected to the RPi via a USB cable.
Most of the time (every once in a while it does work), it seems that the photo capture event isn't firing or gphoto2 isn't detecting it.
When I take a photo it says this:

`UNKNOWN PTP Property d107 changed UNKNOWN FocusInfo eosversion=0,size=5184x3456,size2=5184x3456,points={{0,743,117,181},{-839,393,172,129},{839,393,172,129},{-1394,0,172,129},{0,0,224,222},{1394,0,172,129},{-839,-393,172,129},{839,-393,172,129},{0,-743,117,181}},select={},unknown={10000000ffff} UNKNOWN PTP Property d108 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d1b8 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d1b7 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d1b0 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d107 changed UNKNOWN FocusInfo eosversion=0,size=5184x3456,size2=5184x3456,points={{0,743,117,181},{-839,393,172,129},{839,393,172,129},{-1394,0,172,129},{0,0,224,222},{1394,0,172,129},{-839,-393,172,129},{839,-393,172,129},{0,-743,117,181}},select={},unknown={10000000ffff} UNKNOWN PTP Property d108 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d1b8 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d104 changed UNKNOWN PTP Property d104 changed`

So it seems that the focus event is being detected, but not the actual capturing of the photo.

This is my command:

`gphoto2 --filename "%y%m%d%H%M_1.%C" --debug --debug-logfile="/home/user1/gphoto-debug.txt" --capture-tethered`

though when I do --capture-image-and-download it does work, the photo is taken and downloaded to the computer, but my camera is being triggered by a sensor so it can't be gphoto triggering it.

This is the content of the --debug-logfile:

`12.588002 ptp                         (2): event 0: EOS prop d11b (EOS_AvailableShots) info record, datasize is 4
12.588047 ptp                         (2): event 0: currentvalue of d11b is 1635
12.588095 ptp                         (2): event 1: EOS prop d11c (EOS_CaptureDestination) info record, datasize is 4
12.588133 ptp                         (2): event 1: currentvalue of d11c is 2
12.588179 ptp                         (2): event 2: EOS prop d120 (EOS_ImageFormat) info record, datasize is 20
12.588216 ptp                         (2): event 2: currentvalue of d120 is 1
12.588252 ptp                         (2): event 2: decoded imageformat, currentvalue of d120 is d300
12.588297 ptp                         (2): event 3: EOS prop d11e (EOS_CurrentStorage) info record, datasize is 4
12.588335 ptp                         (2): event 3: currentvalue of d11e is 20001
12.588417 ptp                         (2): event 4: EOS prop d11c (EOS_CaptureDestination) info record, datasize is 4
12.588454 ptp                         (2): event 4: currentvalue of d11c is 2
12.588499 ptp                         (2): event 5: EOS prop d11f (EOS_CurrentFolder) info record, datasize is 4
12.588536 ptp                         (2): event 5: currentvalue of d11f is 91900000
12.588569 ptp                         (2): BAD: i 6, entries 6
12.588616 ptp_usb_sendreq             (2): Sending PTP_OC 0x9116 (EOS_GetEvent) request...
12.588652 gp_port_write               (3): Writing 12 = 0xc bytes to port...
12.588800 gp_port_write               (3): Wrote   12 = 0xc bytes to port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 01 00 16 91-a3 01 00 00              ............

12.588854 ptp_usb_getdata             (2): Reading PTP_OC 0x9116 (EOS_GetEvent) data...
12.588890 gp_port_read                (3): Reading 1024 = 0x400 bytes from port...
12.590792 gp_port_read                (3): Read    20 = 0x14 out of 1024 bytes from port: (hexdump of 20 bytes)
0000  14 00 00 00 02 00 16 91-a3 01 00 00 08 00 00 00  ................
0010  00 00 00 00            -                         ....

12.590847 ptp_usb_getresp             (2): Reading PTP_OC 0x9116 (EOS_GetEvent) response...
12.590884 gp_port_read                (3): Reading 1024 = 0x400 bytes from port...
12.591884 gp_port_read                (3): Read    12 = 0xc out of 1024 bytes from port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 03 00 01 20-a3 01 00 00              ....... ....

12.591946 ptp_usb_sendreq             (2): Sending PTP_OC 0x9114 (EOS_SetRemoteMode) (0x0) request...
12.591983 gp_port_write               (3): Writing 16 = 0x10 bytes to port...
12.592132 gp_port_write               (3): Wrote   16 = 0x10 bytes to port: (hexdump of 16 bytes)
0000  10 00 00 00 01 00 14 91-a4 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

12.592186 ptp_usb_getresp             (2): Reading PTP_OC 0x9114 (EOS_SetRemoteMode) response...
12.592222 gp_port_read                (3): Reading 1024 = 0x400 bytes from port...
12.610694 gp_port_read                (3): Read    12 = 0xc out of 1024 bytes from port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 03 00 01 20-a4 01 00 00              ....... ....

12.610760 ptp_usb_sendreq             (2): Sending PTP_OC 0x9115 (EOS_SetEventMode) (0x0) request...
12.610796 gp_port_write               (3): Writing 16 = 0x10 bytes to port...
12.611018 gp_port_write               (3): Wrote   16 = 0x10 bytes to port: (hexdump of 16 bytes)
0000  10 00 00 00 01 00 15 91-a5 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

12.611070 ptp_usb_getresp             (2): Reading PTP_OC 0x9115 (EOS_SetEventMode) response...
12.611107 gp_port_read                (3): Reading 1024 = 0x400 bytes from port...
12.613008 gp_port_read                (3): Read    12 = 0xc out of 1024 bytes from port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 03 00 01 20-a5 01 00 00              ....... ....

12.613063 ptp_usb_sendreq             (2): Sending PTP_OC 0x1003 (Close session) request...
12.613099 gp_port_write               (3): Writing 12 = 0xc bytes to port...
12.616553 gp_port_write               (3): Wrote   12 = 0xc bytes to port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 01 00 03 10-a6 01 00 00              ............

12.616615 ptp_usb_getresp             (2): Reading PTP_OC 0x1003 (Close session) response...
12.616651 gp_port_read                (3): Reading 1024 = 0x400 bytes from port...
12.628735 gp_port_read                (3): Read    12 = 0xc out of 1024 bytes from port: (hexdump of 12 bytes)
0000  0c 00 00 00 03 00 01 20-a6 01 00 00              ....... ....

12.628994 gp_port_close               (2): Closing port...
12.630122 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 0:0x198fdc0 (status 0)
12.630184 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 1:0x199e308 (status 0)
12.630235 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 2:0x19896d0 (status 0)
12.630316 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 3:0x198da80 (status 0)
12.630364 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 4:0x19902b0 (status 0)
12.630410 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 5:0x198cb08 (status 0)
12.630456 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 6:0x19a1070 (status 0)
12.630502 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 7:0x198f250 (status 0)
12.630547 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 8:0x1989a80 (status 0)
12.630592 _close_async_interrupts     (2): canceling transfer 9:0x19a1170 (status 0)
12.630654 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x198fdc0 with status 3
12.630691 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x198fdc0 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.630736 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x199e308 with status 3
12.630770 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x199e308 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.630813 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x19896d0 with status 3
12.630846 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x19896d0 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.630889 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x198da80 with status 3
12.630923 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x198da80 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.630965 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x19902b0 with status 3
12.630999 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x19902b0 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.631040 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x198cb08 with status 3
12.631074 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x198cb08 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.631117 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x19a1070 with status 3
12.631150 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x19a1070 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.631193 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x198f250 with status 3
12.631226 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x198f250 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.631269 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x1989a80 with status 3
12.631303 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x1989a80 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.631345 _cb_irq                     (2): 0x19a1170 with status 3
12.631379 _cb_irq                     (2): Transfer 0x19a1170 should be in LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED, but is 3!
12.632977 gp_filesystem_reset         (2): resetting filesystem
12.633021 gp_filesystem_lru_clear     (2): Clearing fscache LRU list...
12.633053 gp_filesystem_lru_clear     (2): fscache LRU list already empty
12.633085 delete_all_folders          (2): Internally deleting all folders from '/'...
12.633117 lookup_folder               (2): Lookup folder '/'...
12.633149 lookup_folder               (2): Found! / is 0x1973d80
12.633181 recurse_delete_folder       (2): Recurse delete folder 0x1973d80//
12.633214 delete_all_files            (2): Delete all files in folder 0x1973d80//
12.633244 gp_port_free                (2): Freeing port...
12.633273 gp_port_close               (2): Closing port...
12.633964 gp_filesystem_reset         (2): resetting filesystem
12.634006 gp_filesystem_lru_clear     (2): Clearing fscache LRU list...
12.634037 gp_filesystem_lru_clear     (2): fscache LRU list already empty
12.634069 delete_all_folders          (2): Internally deleting all folders from '/'...
12.634100 lookup_folder               (2): Lookup folder '/'...
12.634131 lookup_folder               (2): Found! / is 0x1973d80
12.634162 recurse_delete_folder       (2): Recurse delete folder 0x1973d80//
12.634194 delete_all_files            (2): Delete all files in folder 0x1973d80//`

--capture-image-and-download works
--capture-tethered most of the time does not work, the capture event isn't fired or detected